# SSBO writes are not visible

Tags: opengl, glsl, particle-system, particles, compute-shader

I am working on a small particle system using OpenGL.
The problem is that updating the positions in the compute shader do not seem to work.

Here's the code:

1. Buffers

   ```
   struct ParticleInfo {

       Vec4f position; // w: s coordinate
       Vec4f normal; // w: t coordinate
       float materialIndex;
       Vec3f oldPosition;

   };
   ```
2. Init buffers

   ```
   glGenVertexArrays(1, &mParticleVAO);
   glBindVertexArray(mParticleVAO);

   glGenBuffers(1, &mParticleVBO);
   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mParticleVBO);

   glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(ParticleInfo) * mNumParticles, particleData.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

   glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
   glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(ParticleInfo), (void*)NULL);

   glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
   glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(ParticleInfo), (void*)(NULL + sizeof(Vec4f)));

   glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
   glVertexAttribPointer(2, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(ParticleInfo), (void*)(NULL + 2*sizeof(Vec4f)));

   glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
   glBindVertexArray(0);
   ```
3. update buffers with a compute shader

   ```
        gl->setUniform(mParticleMoveProgram->getUniformLoc("numParticles"), mNumParticles);
   glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, mParticleVBO);
   glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1, mAttractorSSBO);

   int localSizeX = 64*8;

   int groupSizeX = (mNumParticles + localSizeX - 1) / localSizeX;

   glDispatchCompute(groupSizeX, 1, 1);
   glMemoryBarrier(GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS);

   glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, 0);
   glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1, 0);
   ```
4. shader code

   ```
   #version 450

   layout(local_size_x = 64) in;

   struct ParticleInfo {

       vec4 position; // modify only the position;
       vec4 normal;
       float materialIndex;
       vec3 oldPosition;

   };

   struct Attractor {

       vec3 position;
       float mass;

   };

   layout(binding = 0, std430) buffer ParticleArray {

       ParticleInfo particles[];

   };

   layout(binding = 1, std430) buffer AttractorArray {

       Attractor attractors[];

   };

   uniform int numParticles;


   vec3 verlet(in vec3 a, in vec3 x, in vec3 xOld, in float dt) {

       return 2.0 * x - xOld + a * dt*dt;

   }

   void main() {

       const int PARTICLES_PER_THREAD = 8;

       int index = int(gl_LocalInvocationIndex)*PARTICLES_PER_THREAD;

       if (index >= numParticles) return;

       Attractor attr = attractors[0];

       const float G = 9.8;

       for (int i = 0; i < PARTICLES_PER_THREAD; ++i)
       {


           particles[i+index].position = vec4(0.0);
           particles[i+index].normal = vec4(0.0);
           particles[i+index].oldPosition = vec3(0.0);
       }



   }
   ```

Comment: By not work: I mean that particles remain at the same initial position where as I would like to set all of them to position 0.

Comment: How do you know that they are in the same position? Are you rendering it and not seeing them move?

Comment: The particles resemble a specific shape. They are all sampled from triangles in some mesh.

Comment: Your cpu side `ParticleInfo` structure doesn't match the alignment rules of `std430`, so the `ParticleInfo` and `Attractor` in the shader will see different data, especially since you use an array of these structs. You could  make your (and your GPU's) life much easier if you'd pack that scalar `float` together with that `vec3` into a `vec4`.

Comment: As a supplement to derhass's statement, please see [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172696/should-i-ever-use-a-vec3-inside-of-a-uniform-buffer-or-shader-storage-buffer-o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as @derhass commented. The memory structure didn't match. There seemed to be also a problem with proper indexing per thread. I fixed it by setting the index per thread as:

```
index = PARTICLES_PER_THREAD * int(gl_WorkGroupSize.x * gl_WorkGroupID.x + gl_LocalInvocationID.x);
```

Thanks for the help.